# How do I get data from Arel output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I'm successfully following some of the commands listed [here](https://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html) and applying them to my own tables.

How do I turn the output into actual records/data ? Presently it's returning some output which I can assign to a variable, but I do not understand this output at all.. it doesn't look like an array or hash (but perhaps it is), and I do not understand how to access its contents (I want to use the output in a rails view, but at the least would like to access the table records in the console where I'm executing the Arel code)

For example, say I have two tables; User and Product as follows:

```
User = [{:id => 1, :name => "Joe", :email => "joe@gmail.com"}, {:id => 2, :name => "Jane", :email => "jane@gmail.com"}]

Product = [{:product_name => "Car Tire", :brand => "BMW", :last_edited_by => 1}, {:product_name => "Paint Brush", :brand => "Dulux", :last_edited_by => nil}, {:product_name => "Dog Biscuits", :brand => "Bowow Snacks", :last_edited_by => 2}, {:product_name => "Game", :brand => "Westwood", :last_edited_by => 1}]
```

Suppose I want to join the two tables User.id = Product.last_edited_by

In SQL it would be as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
JOIN Product
WHERE users.id = products.last_edited_by
```

Now if I plug this into scuttle.io to convert to Arel, it gives:

```
User.select(Arel.star).where(
  User.arel_table[:id].eq(Product.arel_table[:last_edited_by])
).joins(
  User.arel_table.join(Product.arel_table).on(null).join_sources
)
```

But trying this returns: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Attempting to emulate advice given [here](https://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html), I come up with another approach:

```
users.project(Arel.star).join(User).on(Product[:last_edited_by].eq(User[:id]))
```

But this returns: NoMethodError: undefined method `project' for Array..

A final point, if I run

```
users = Arel::Table.new(User)
output = users.project(users[:id].as("id"), users[:id].count.as("count")).group("id")
```

I get some output which looks almost meaningful, but I don't know how to return that into something I can make sense of, and I wouldn't know how to use it if I provided it to a rails view

Comment: Could you add some example code please? What you're currently doing and what you expect from this? More info on formatting questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What commands are you running, exactly? What result to do get? What are you trying to achieve? You need to be more specific.